# Can't read csv file in python without mentioning whole path

Tags: python, csv, streamlit

I have a csv file in the same directory with py file
If i read it this way :

`heart_data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Python\heart_disease_data.csv')`
It works without any problem.
but this way :
`heart_data = pd.read_csv(r'heart_disease_data.csv')`
It doesn't work, even though it's in the same directory.

I get this message in streamlit :
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'heart_disease_data.csv'`

any thoughts ?

Comment: Is it possible that you misspelled it?

Comment: Check `import os;os.listdir(os.curdir)` and make sure your CSV file exists within the current directory.

Comment: I assume "even though it is in the same directory" means "the same directory as the script". If you genuinely have trouble opening a file in your current working directory, please [edit] to clarify (and ping me to get this reopened, provided you have added enough details to show us that the file is really there and that it still doesn't work).